# Error with dependencies higher than expected

Tags: kali-linux, dependencies

I try to make msfupdate inside the actual kali Linux sana repository. I don't understand the dependencies. for ex. I have xpdf <= 3.03-11 but 3.03-10 should be installed - where's the problem?

If I understand it well, **<=3.03-11 doesn't mean 3.03-10 is out of range**, because **3.03-10 < 3.03-11** is true, right? First I got an error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libfontconfig1: Damaged: xpdf (<= 3.03-11) but 3.03-10 to be installed
E: Error caused by interruptions pkgProblemResolver :: Resolve; This could have been caused by retained packages.
```

I ran apt-get install reinstall xpdf and it seems to be installed. I tried again msfupdate, there's the next error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:.
  network-manager-gnome: Depends: network-manager (> = 0.9.10) but 0.9.4.0-10 to be installed
  ppp: Damaged: network-manager (<0.9.8.8-7 ~) but 0.9.4.0-10 to be installed
E: Error caused by interruptions pkgProblemResolver :: Resolve; This could have been caused by retained packages
```

Also **<0.9.8.8-7 doesn't mean 0.9.4.0-10 is out of range** because **0.9.4.0-10 < 0.9.8.8-7** is also a true statement.

My question: I don't know how much dependency errors are waiting to appear. Should I continue installing every error message output manually or is there a better way? I found this topic about a bug. I don't know but maybe it depends to my problem https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=727070
.
Maybe someone could find a more moderate title for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently these aren't dependencies. Look at the message

> libfontconfig1: Damaged: xpdf (<= 3.03-11) but 3.03-10 to be installed

These are packages which **damage** another, so the xpdf must **not** for it to be <= 3.03-11 to be installable.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand this part "must not for it to be <= 3.03-11 to be installable". Do you mean i need <3.03-11 or >3.03-11? If the first statement is true, i cant see errors because i have 3.03-10 and thats <3.03-11. if the second statement is true i would assume i have to upgrade my actual package, right? But if that is the highest version number in the repo, how can i upgrade it? i also ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 2 times today - my laptop crashes twice and i had to resetup. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the push but maybe someone could explain me that. It seems @Thomas Weinbrenner is not responding anymore but i have a problem understanding his answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was late night here and I had to sleep.   You need a package > 3.03-11, but I can't tell you where to get it.